# Android Conflicting HttpClient With Library

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-library, apache-httpcomponents

I have a library (not an Android library) that uses the Apache HTTP libraries. I want to use this library in an Android application. It also needs to be used with other types of frameworks. Will this cause any conflicts with the Apache libraries in Android, and is there any way to make it so that when it is included in Android it will use Android's Apache libraries? It would be really inconvenient to have to pass in the HTTP client to use.

Comment: If your used library does not physically include the appache-library (it's jar file for example), there is no problem. Java will just check if the classes are in your build path, which should be the case when you build an Android application.

Comment: How else would my library make use of Apache's HTTP libraries if it isn't physically included? I think I may have been a little vague with my question. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this cause any conflicts with the Apache libraries in Android

That depends upon how you define "conflicts".

You do not control the runtime classpath, and the firmware always wins. Hence, the Android version of HTTPClient will be used, for all HTTPClient classes that exist in the Android SDK.

If your other library is dependent upon a *different version* of HTTPClient, you may be in trouble.

> is there any way to make it so that when it is included in Android it will use Android's Apache libraries

You have no choice: Android's classes will be used, wherever there is a duplicate.

Comment: So if in my library I make sure to always use the same version of HTTPClient that Android does, I shouldn't have any problems using my library in a "Java" project or an "Android" project?

Comment: @Eliezer: Yes. Your challenge may be in finding a JAR of HTTPClient that matches Android's version (4.0.3b?). The closer you can get, the better, in that there is less chance of an API change that will cause you problems. You will probably want a good test suite that can exercise your library in Android and in a traditional Java VM to make sure everything is working as expected. Also, bear in mind that HTTPClient is no longer the recommended solution in Android -- Google now recommends the old `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: `HttpUrlConnection` is a standard java class right? I know this is a bit off-topic but would you suggest using that for outside of Android as well (especially since if that is the class Google recommends for Android I would want to use it, and I'd rather just use one class instead of trying to figure out how to use `HttpUrlConnection` for Android and `HTTPClient` for everywhere else)?

Comment: @Eliezer: "`HttpUrlConnection` is a standard java class right?" -- yes. "would you suggest using that for outside of Android as well" -- there's nothing wrong with doing that AFAIK.